# Override padding for mat tree

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am using this example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/goolrxyjjee?file=app%2Fcdk-tree-flat-example.ts) to build a `mat-tree` using a flat `datasource`. Now I want to override the default `padding-left` which is `40px` for all the following children. This is how I am doing it:

```
mat-tree-node:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

This works, but only sets `16px` padding on the level 2 of the tree nodes. The rest of the nested children do not accumulate the 16px as I keep on expanding them. Is it possible to override `matTreeNodePadding` directive?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to use the api documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/api#MatTreeNodePadding) to resolve the issue. Had to pass in the selector input for `matTreeNodePadding` indentation in this case.

```
<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding matTreeNodePaddingIndent="20">
```

This would override the existing default 40px left padding to 20px.

Comment: In another way, you can take input as ```<mat-tree-node matTreeNodePadding [matTreeNodePaddingIndent] = treeNodePadding> ``` and set its input value in your component typescript file as `@input('cdkTreeNodePadding') treeNodePadding: number = 20;`

Comment: 20 seems to be the magic number.

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles are always going to overwrite any styles you have in an external stylesheet. This means that unless you throw an `!important` onto the end of your padding definition, you aren't going to be able to overwrite the padding you're receiving from the directive.

You can do that with this code:

```
mat-tree-node {
  padding-left: 16px !important;
}
```

Note: Using `!important` will overwrite the padding but it's also seen as a big "no no" with CSS. If you can prevent the directive from appending padding to each element automatically, that would be a better solution.

Comment: This solution puts all the levels at `padding-left` of 16px. I want to have an incremental 16x2 padding on each level expanding from the root.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. This is going to keep getting messier as the HTML output is completely flat. Ideally these elements would be nested to allow for us to target children and to improve the accessibility of the page. All of that said, you can target elements by their inline styles: 

`div[style*="display:block"] { ... }`

This means you could target the different levels of padding you're receiving from the directive manually: 


`mat-tree-node[style*="padding-left: 40px"] { padding-left: 16px !important; }`

`mat-tree-node[style*="padding-left: 80px"] { padding-left: 32px !important; }`